# Xamarin Android, specify MIME type when downloading files using CrossDownloadManager

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, mime-types

I'm trying to download a file which is stored in db, using url.

Below is the sample code for download

```cs
var dirMainToCreate = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Constants.AppDirectory);

if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(dirMainToCreate))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dirMainToCreate);
}

var dirContentToCreate = System.IO.Path.Combine(dirMainToCreate, contentdirectory);
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(dirContentToCreate))
{
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dirContentToCreate);
}    

CrossDownloadManager.Current.PathNameForDownloadedFile = new Func<IDownloadFile, string>(file => {
    return Path.Combine(dirContentToCreate, filename);
});


(CrossDownloadManager.Current as DownloadManagerImplementation).IsVisibleInDownloadsUi = true;
```

File = CrossDownloadManager.Current.CreateDownloadFile(Constants.Url+"/Files/GetFile?id="+ fileId, new Dictionary {
            { "Authorization", "Bearer "+this.Token }
         }
    );

CrossDownloadManager.Current.Start(File);

My issue is that the file gets downloaded successfully, but it can't be opened.

Comment: are you sure to use the correct file path to open ?

Comment: yes, i can see the downloaded file in 'Downloas' but they won't open

Comment: are there any errors when opening it ?

Comment: When I try to open the file, a toast message appears saying 'Can't open file'

Comment: try to save to the path "Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads" ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally used the other approach, using *WebClient*

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-download-files-in-xamarin-forms/

```
    public void DownloadFile(string url, string token, string folder)
    {
        string pathToNewFolder = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, folder);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToNewFolder);

        try
        {
            using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.Headers.Add("API_KEY", App.Api_key);
                client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);



                using (Stream rawStream = client.OpenRead(url))
                {
                    string fileName = string.Empty;
                    string contentDisposition = client.ResponseHeaders["content-disposition"];
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition))
                    {
                        string lookFor = "filename=";
                        int index = contentDisposition.IndexOf(lookFor, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
                        if (index >= 0)
                            fileName = contentDisposition.Substring(index + lookFor.Length);
                    }

                    string pathToNewFile = Path.Combine(pathToNewFolder, fileName);

                    client.DownloadFile(url, pathToNewFile);

                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (OnFileDownloaded != null)
                OnFileDownloaded.Invoke(this, new DownloadEventArgs(false));
        }
    }
```

The only problem here is that the OS is not showing its native downloading progress-bar and also doesn't gives a notification when file download is complete